# How do I get notified about a new question in my favorite tag?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, tag-watching

Is there a way to get notified if a new question is posted in one of my Favorite tag other than me clicking on the tag or browsing through new questions all the times?

I have a favorite tag (Bloomberg) with low monthly number of questions in it (around 30-40).

And since I can be of great help in that area to other people, I would like to see if there a notification system in place (such as email).

Comment: With all due respect , even though the answer to the above question is similar to the answer to my question. The questions themselves are quite different

Comment: This is not a dupe. Voting to reopen. (guess I missed something two years back)

Comment: An updated version, reflecting some changes on the site: [How to subscribe to tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315135)

Answer (score 9):

Mouse over the tag, and in the popup click on 'subscribe' or 'rss':

[image: tag popup]

Subscribing means you'll get emailed for new questions (you'll be sent a confirmation email first); the RSS link should take you to your RSS reader.

Email subscriptions can be managed on your [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) profile (click on your name in the top bar); there is a 'subscriptions' tab there, tag subscriptions are grouped under the 'Filters' header:

[image: tag filter subscriptions]

Comment: OK. and what happens after that? I'm not used RSS before. What I need to use it?

Comment: @JoeTatavaran: You install a RSS reader, or a RSS extension for your browser. If you just want email, use the `subscribe` link instead.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/News_aggregator) for a general overview and options.

Comment: @Joe after you subscribe you can  change the settings through your [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/3013406/joe-tatavaran), you will see "subscription" tab there.