# Website Notifications for Favorited Tags

Tags: feature-request, notifications, tag-watching

I think it would be helpful if I could get a notification when a new question is posted for a tag that I have favorited, this could be an opt in option so people can choose to leave it off if they so wish.

Comment: You can already have those sent to your email once in 3 hours, isn't it enough?

Comment: @shadowwizard I know about the emails but those aren't very useful. I meant notifications like those red notifications you get at the top of the site if for instance someone tags you

Comment: Yes, and it was already asked for.

Comment: @ShadowWizard what do you mean? that question is asking for emails?

Comment: No, I mean that your question is closed of duplicate of other question, in case you missed the banner.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes and that question isn't a duplicate of this because they are asking for emails. I'm asking for the in site notification.

Comment: No it's not just emails. It's about getting instant notification, where email was given as an example.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm sorry but I do not understand. If I subscribe I get sent a confirmation email, which I click on and then I will get notified by email every x time for a new question in that tag. Are you saying I will get a website notification as well if I do this?

Comment: No. I am saying that what you asked for here in this question 18 hours ago, was already asked for in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188223/how-do-i-get-notified-about-a-new-question-in-my-favorite-tag) posted on this site bit more than 2 years ago. This is also known as "duplicate". Sorry, but I can't explain it any better, guess language barrier prevents us from communicating better.

Comment: Note that the other question still did not get any official response, so it's considered a pending request: same as yours, so no point leaving two identical requests open. What we do here on MSE is closing one as duplicate of the other.

Comment: @ShadowWizard but it's not a duplicate because the other question is asking for email notification "I would like to see if there a notification system in place (such as email)." and then the answer to that was explaining to them that there is an email notification in place. So that question should be closed as the feature they requested already exists. This question however asks for in website notifications which I'm pretty sure does not exist yet.

Comment: "such as" implies it is only an *example*, one way out of many other possible ways, where inbox notifications (which cause red number you mentioned) are yet another way to achieve the same thing. Same request, more than one way to implement it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I disagree, they aren't requesting anything, they have asked a question "how can I" and someone answered "by clicking subscribe you can get exactly what you want". I'm asking for a specific function, for an option to get a website notification when there's a new question in a favorited tag. Also that question is two years old, I doubt anyone's going to action on it because they're not requesting any feature.

Comment: guess I can't convince you, but I am not going to reopen this.