# Notification about new Stack Overflow questions to another e-mail address?

Tags: feature-request, questions, email, tag-watching

I want to help others on Stack Overflow. I've set a watched tag. Is it possible to be notified about new questions with this tag to a special e-mail address?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the main issue is that you want to specify an email address - which might be different from the address you have currently in your email settings.

As far as I can tell, if you use [tag filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-filters/info), you can choose an arbitrary email address which you want to use for notifications.

If you go to https://stackexchange.com/filters/, you can set-up a filter for a specific tag on one site or multiple sites. And you can choose whether you want to receive an email with new questions too - the options are once per day, every 3 hours or every 15 minutes.

[image: screenshot]

As a test, I have just tried to use a filter for the tag [discussion on all sites](https://stackexchange.com/filters/440220/discussion-metas).
And as a test, I have set it up for "every 15 minutes". (I wanted to use something with relatively high volume of questions - so that if it works, then I receive some notification relatively soon. I suppose that the tag [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) over *all* meta sites fulfills this requirement.)

So far I have received an email asking to confirm my subscription. I did that, and I'll report later whether the test worked.

An a few hour later, I can confirm that I received several emails with new question on the email address that I entered.

---

You can manage your subscriptions not only through the page with filters, but also in the [subscriptions tab of your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=subscriptions). This is described in the answer here: [How do I get notified about a new question in my favorite tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188223#188225) (The first part of the answer is something that works differently - instead of subscribe/unsubscribe you now get watch/unwatch tag. But possibility to manage your subscription in your network profile seems to work in the same way as back then - judging by the screenshot.)

Comment: Keep in mind that filter subscriptions are public and anyone can see them on your network profile. I have a [feature-request] post about that: [Why are Filter Subscriptions public? And can that be changed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382966/348196)

Comment: With an appropriate client (say, [Thunderbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Thunderbird)—though it is sort of a hidden feature in it), RSS feeds can work exactly the same as e-mail. It even works for YouTube channels ([sample RSS feed URL](https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCxzC4EngIsMrPmbm6Nxvb-A)), thus independence of the recommendation algorithm and being logged in (subscriptions). I don't know if RSS feeds are supported for this case.